# Showing $\frac{1}{x \ln (x)}$ is in $L^p$ for all $p>0$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, banach-spaces

I was trying to find a function which is in $L^p[0,1]$ for all $p$ but not in $L^{\infty}[0,1]$. I asked my professor, when he said it's $\frac{1}{x \ln (x)}$. However, I am having a hard time to show how is this true. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: I was wondering if the property holds for $\frac{1}{x(ln\frac{1}{x})^2}$.

Comment: It isn't in $L^p[0,1]$ for any $p\ge1$.

Comment: Thank you, just a quick follow up. Do you think $\frac{1}{x(ln\frac{1}{x})^2}$ satisfies the property

Comment: The $\frac{1}{x}$ is fairly unnecessary since it's in a $\ln$ so it's only a change of sign, but anyway, I do not know which name they might have in the English world, but integrals of the type $\displaystyle\int_0^a \frac{1}{x^\alpha |\ln(x)|^\beta} \mathrm{d}x$ ($a < +\infty$ doesn't matter for the convergence) are known as "Bertrand integrals" in French and their convergence or divergence is well-established, see [this Wikipedia link](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Int%C3%A9grale_impropre#Int%C3%A9grales_de_Bertrand) (it's in French but you should be able to understand what's said)... 1/2

Comment: ... However it seems like in the English world they are not as standard. 2/2